# GATE CSE 2009, Which of the following is FALSE?

Tags: formal-languages

This is a question from GATE CSE 2009.

> Which of the following is FALSE?
>
> A]  There is a unique minimal DFA for every regular language.
>
> B]  Every NFA can be converted to an equivalent PDA.
>
> C]  Complement of every context-free language is recursive.
>
> D]  Every non-deterministic PDA can be converted to an equivalent
> deterministic PDA.

The answer provided to me (without any explanation) is B, which I think is wrong.

Here is my approach.

> A] Every RL has an equivalent DFA and there is one unique minimal DFA
> for a given RL. [so True]
>
> B] Since RL are proper sub-set of CFL and every RL has equivalent FA
> and every CFL has equivalent PDA, every FA can be converted to PDA but
> not vice versa. [so True]
>
> C] Given a CFL we can create an equivalent Total TM [RECURSIVE],
> RECURSIVE languages are closed under complement. [so True]
>
> D] This is only remaining option and by method of elimination answer.

Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A is true, but I don't find your argument convincing (it simply restates the claim). See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63171/how-to-prove-that-minimal-dfa-is-unique) for example.

B is not the correct answer to this problem, because as you say it's true. Your reasoning isn't very formal though, and swaps some reduction orders. A correct reduction would be NFA → (superset construction)→ DFA → (trivial) → PDA.

C seems fine to me.

D is indeed left over, and is indeed false. Inherently ambiguous context-free languages can be recognized by nondeterministic PDAs, but not by deterministic PDAs.